# Update mysql query not updating table but only delete the data in the specified field

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, odbc

I have a problem with my update query it is not updating the specified fields but onlye deleting them.

This is the query:

```
Dim myConnection As OdbcConnection
Dim myCommand As OdbcCommand


myConnection = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Database=usermanagement;Server=localhost;UID=root;")
myConnection.Open()

If myConnection.State = 0 Then
    myConnection.Open()
End If


myCommand = New OdbcCommand("update rooms set rmname='" + Request.Form("rmnames") + "',description='" + Request.Form("description") + "', rmprice='" + Request.Form("rmprices") + "' where room_id='" + Request.Form("rooms_id") + "'", myConnection)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConnection.Close()

Response.Redirect("admin.aspx")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm asking for your code, caz' it might be a few reasons

Comment: hello sir, I was able to solved, thank you for your response.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue then please add an answer and accept it.  That way we won't waste our time reading your question only to find out that you don't need help any more.  Also, someone else with the same issue may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myConnection As OdbcConnection
Dim myCommand As OdbcCommand


myConnection = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Database=usermanagement;Server=localhost;UID=root;")
myConnection.Open()

If myConnection.State = 0 Then
    myConnection.Open()
End If

myCommand = New OdbcCommand("update rooms set rmname='" + Request.Form("item") + "',description='" + Request.Form("descr") + "', rmprice='" + Request.Form("rate") + "' where room_id=" + Request.Form("room_id"), myConnection)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConnection.Close()

Response.Redirect("admin.aspx")
```

This was my answer.

Comment: kindly accept it if it resolved ur issue, it would be great if u mention the main thing which make ur issue resolved

Comment: @coder he delete single quota mark near by ID column in a WHERE clause. I didn't thought that Odbc can't resolve this... In Sqlcommand *ID = 5* and *ID = '5'* equals...